# How can I do a AIC comparison between all possible models from combination of 10 elements in R?

Tags: r, combinations, linear-regression, data-modeling

My data include the average of variable `CC` in 10 different size buffers (`CC1`, `CC2`, `CC3`, …, `CC10`) as well as the abundance of birds which is the same for all 10 buffer sizes. what I want to do is making all possible linear models from the combination of these buffers and calculating `AIC` for each model and finding the best model (with lest `AIC` value). For example some of my models are:

```
MODEL1 <- lm(ABUNDANCE~CC1)
MODEL2 <- lm(ABUNDANCE~CC1+CC2)
MODEL3 <- lm(ABUNDANCE~CC1+CC2+CC3)
```

I tried to make all possible models from combination of my 10 buffer elements using this code:

```
library(gdata)
library(gplots)
library(gmodels)
library(gtools)

vars<-c('CC1','CC2','CC3',’CC4’,'CC5','CC6','CC7','CC8','CC9','CC10')

indexes<-unique(apply(combinations(length(vars), length(vars), repeats=T), 1, unique))

gen.form<-function(x) as.formula(paste("ABUNDANCES",'~',paste( vars[x],collapse='+')))
formulas<-lapply(indexes, gen.form)

formulas
```

The problem is that because formulas is a list I can not apply `AIC` function to it.

Comment: see `MuMIn::dredge`: but note that this is a recipe for overfitting, you'll be fitting 1024 models to your data ...